# `Retrieve a page based on a predefined path using nested set

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, hierarchical-data, nested-lists

I am currently building a CMS and intend to use Joe Celko's nest tree set (MPTT) to retrieve hierarchical data such as a nested deep page based on a defined path. e.g.
example.com/products/phone/specs.

I have a categories tables

```
cat_id    name        lft  rgt
1         products    1    18
2         phone       2    9
3         specs       3    4
4         gallery     5    6
5         price       7    8
6         laptop      10   17
7         specs       11   12
8         gallery     13   14
9         price       15   16
10
```

and a pages table

```
page_id   name    content
1         specs   Here is the specification of the chosen phone
2         price   the price of chosen phone
3         specs   laptop spec
4         price   laptop price
```

This schema can be found on [slqfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8daf6/2)
Unfortunately, i have no idea on how to do this, the closest idea i got from searching online examples even celko's book does assume you only want to "retrieve the single path" to the parent of a node. Whereas, my use case demands that i retrieve the page (and display it) based on the path set by the url as above.
So, i can i achieve this? All valuable suggestions are welcome. thanks.

Comment: Presumably, you've read Mike Hillyer's article too, right?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, i have read his post.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET